# Amplify UPDATE_FAILED API key not found

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I created an application in amplify aws at first I use apiKey for appsync but then I switched to userPool and when I want to push my changes to amplify I got the error apKey not found from cloudFormation stack

i'm searching now how to delete unused api Key